# What is the meaning of use FLAG_ONE_SHOT in a pendingintent which will be used to a notification? Is it necessary?

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Does it mean that I can't jump to the mainActivity multiple times by repeatedly clicking this notification? Is pendingIntent.send() called internally when I clicks the notification? Does this flag become meaningless in the notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` means that the `PendingIntent` will be deleted after it is used **once**. Normally, a `PendingIntent` can hang around if there are other references to it in the system.

This flag can be used to prevent multiple uses of the `PendingIntent`, although my personal experience is that this flag generally causes more problems than it solves.

You asked:

> Is pendingIntent.send() called internally when I clicks the notification?

Yes, that's basically what happens when you click on the UI element associated with the `PendingIntent` in the `Notification`.